# What does ClassName method() => ClassName() mean in Dart?

Tags: dart, flutter

In a Flutter projet, I saw this snippet: `_State createState() => _State();`
What does `ClassName method() => ClassName()` mean in Dart and where is the method `createState()` defined what does all of this mean for Flutter? 
Here is the full code:

```
class Nearby extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _State createState() => _State();
}

class _State extends State<Nearby> {
  GoogleMapController mapController;
  LatLng _center;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getCurrentLocation();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container()
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Dart language tour](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#functions):

> The `=>` expr syntax is a shorthand for `{ return expr; }`. The `=>` notation is sometimes referred to as arrow syntax.

Therefore:

```
_State createState() => _State();
```

means that `createState()` is a function that invokes a `_State` constructor (with no arguments) and returns the newly constructed `_State` object.

As for what it means for Flutter, see the [`StatefulWidget.createState` documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget/createState.html):

> Creates the mutable state for this widget at a given location in the tree.
>
> Subclasses should override this method to return a newly created instance of their associated State subclass

(You also might want to look at the [`StatefulWidget` documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html).)